# Magento Newsletter: How to Remove from Queue

Tags: magento-1.7, php, database, sql, newsletter

Any suggestions how to delete Queue newsletters from Magento? The most I found is to change a sent date to like 100 years from now. :) 
Any way to actually delete the queue?

Using Magento 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at this tables in your database
newsletter_queue
newsletter_queue_link
newsletter_queue_store_link

To delete queue you need, just run this simple query:

> DELETE FROM newsletter_queue WHERE queue_id = "{id}"

{id} - is id of queue you want remove